# How to extract data within a data of a data extension field and lay it out on HTML email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, html

For instance, I have a Data Extension with fields: email and content. Content field contains 5 different sub-data separated with pipe.

```
|             email |                                 content |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------------|
| test1@example.com | 10|name1|companyName1|styles1|industry1 |
| test2@example.com | 20|name2|companyName2|styles2|industry2 |
| test3@example.com | 30|name3|companyName3|styles3|industry3 |
```

Question:

Is there a way to extract the 5 sub-data separately within the 'content' field and lay it down in HTML code for email?

Possible solutions:

1. Create a Query to extract data and distribute the sub-data to other fields of the same row.
2. Fetch sub-data, lay it down on HTML email for sending.

Any help with the syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you retrieve your DE content using one of the [lookup functions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/), you can build a rowset on a single column value using the [BuildRowSetFromString()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromString) function.

Something like this:

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "test1@example.com"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"email desc","email", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        var @email, @content, @rowCount2, @rows2, @row2, @content1, @content2, @content3
        set @row = row(@rows,@i) 
        set @email = field(@row,"email")
        set @content = field(@row,"content")

        set @rows2 = BuildRowSetFromString(@content,"|")
        set @rowCount2 = rowcount(@rows2)

        if @rowCount2  > 0 then
          set @row2 = row(@rows2,1)
          set @content1 = field(@row2,1)
          set @content2 = field(@row2,2)
          set @content3 = field(@row2,3)
        endif

        ]%%

        Row %%=v(@i)=%%
        <br>email: %%=v(@email )=%%
        <br>content: %%=v(@content)=%%
        <br>content1: %%=v(@content1)=%%
        <br>content2: %%=v(@content2)=%%
        <br>content3: %%=v(@content3)=%%

    %%[

    next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Reference:

[AMPScript Lookup Examples](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)

Comment: Hi Adam.  Thanks for sharing this code.  I just can't seem to make it work yet.  One quick question in your code somewhere at line #5.  There is this "email desc" in the set function.  Did you mean "content" on this instead?

Comment: No, I mean `email desc`, which means sort the rowset by email address, descending, per the [lookuporderedrows()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/LookupOrderedRows.html) documentation

Comment: Right. I was thinking desc is description. :) let me try it again. thanks.

Comment: Hi Adam.  I tried your solution and I get this error:

Unable to generate preview
Invalid field index (parameter 2) passed to Field function. Index must be less than or equal to the row column count.
Index Value: 2
Column Count: 1
Function: field(@row2,2)

I used the exact same data extension, fields and data.  Got any idea why?

Comment: Thanks, Adam.  with few tweaks.  I was able to make it work.  thanks for the guidance.